# Android JNI Threads not running concurrently

Tags: android, c++, concurrency, java-native-interface

I have a C++ library that runs tasks in several threads concurrently. When using the library in a command line application (both on Linux desktop and Android) the total runtime is slightly more than the runtime of the slowest thread, which is what I'd expect. When linking the library into a Java android app via the JNI however, the total runtime is slightly more than the summation of the thread runtime.

Is there any reason the threads wouldn't be running concurrently?

Comment: If your Android device has only 2 cores, and one core is locked on UI thread, this would show symptoms similar to what you report. But usually these days, there are 4 cores and no justified reason for a library not to use all of them. But maybe the cause is that your library relies on some external agent that will create the threads, and it does not work as expected when wrapped in Java.

Comment: The handset I'm testing this on has a Snapdragon 845 with 8 cores.